# Apache Timeout directive not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, tcp, timeout

I have configured /etc/apache2/apache2.conf with Timeout 5 instead of the default 300. So I understand it should close an incoming connection after 5 seconds of inactivity.

But I make a telnet localhost 80 , wait for 5 and more seconds, and nothing happens. A netstat -na tells me the connection is still ESTABLISHED. I left the connection about 5 minutes and still nothing happened.

Any clues why Apache is not cutting the connection? Or am I misunderstanding the Timeout directive? And in that case, which one should I look for?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do have the right syntax -- it should be in the global server config or a vhost config.

I tested this with 2.2.11 and Timeout closed a connection from another computer and a connection to localhost after 5 seconds. Have you tried from another machine? My config is certainly different, so you may have another setting that keeps localhost connected(?)

I tested with both `nc` and `telnet` and there was no difference either.

Which version of Apache are you using? Are you certain there is nothing coming across the wire (via wireshark or similar)?

Comment: For me it doesn't timeout either. Apache waits indefinitely. (Apache/2.2.8, Ubuntu 8.04)